# Designing a Table to hold Friend Relationship

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I want to design a table which contain a friend Relationship  between two person, so I Designed a table contain the following fields : `FriendId` , `Friend_L`, `Friend_R`

this mean that the person `Frind_L` is a friend to the person `Friend_R`

but this design have a problem that I must add every Friend Relationship  Twice to the table to have ability to figure out who is the Friend for a given person using this query :

```
SELECT Friend_R
FROM Friends
Where Friend_L= ANY INTEGER ;
```

any one have other idea to do that without duplicating every Relationship  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a different query?

```
 SELECT
  Friend_R as Friend
 FROM
  Friends
 WHERE
  Friend_L = :x
UNION
 SELECT
  Friend_L as Friend
 FROM
  Friends
 WHERE
  Friend_R = :x
```

The first is identical to yours, but the UNION with the other query should return all the alternative results.  UNION (without the ALL) takes care of removing duplicates for you as well.

Alternatively, you could use CASE to do it in one, if you really feel the need...

```
SELECT
 CASE WHEN (Friend_L = :x) THEN Friend_R ELSE Friend_L END AS Friend
FROM
 Friends
WHERE
 Friend_L = :x OR Friend_R = :x
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do that. Assume you are looking for relations to a user with id of 20.

```
SELECT *
FROM friends
WHERE left_id = 20 or right_id = 20;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add it twice. Just add it once and use `UNION`:

```
SELECT Friend_R FROM Friends Where Friend_L= ANY INTEGER
UNION
SELECT Friend_L FROM Friends Where Friend_R= ANY INTEGER
```